# Chrome Extension making Extension active only if matches match

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this code for my `background.js`

```
function changeActive(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
     console.log(tab);
     chrome.pageAction.setPopup({
     "popup":"popup.html"
  });
   chrome.pageAction.setIcon({
   "path":"Facebook-icon16.png"
   });
  }
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(changeActive);
```

My manifest has this:

```
...  "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
  "css": ["messenger.css"],
  "js":["messenger.js"],
  "run_at":"document_start"
}
 ],
  "version": "0.2",
 "permissions": [
      "activeTab","tabs"
      ]
   }
```

As you can see I am trying to match if the url is facebook, and then change the icon image and show a pop up as well. I also don't want them to be able to click the icon if it is not on Facebook tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using a content script it is a good idea to utilize **[Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)** in order to inform the background-page that it should change the icon and popup.
E.g.:

**In `messenger.js`:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ onFacebook: true });
```

**In `background.js`:**

```
/* When the content scripts makes contact, 
 * set the page-action's icon and popup */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {
    if (msg.onFacebook === true) {
        chrome.pageAction.setIcon({
            tabId: sender.tab.id,
            path: "path/to/active/icon.png"
        });
        chrome.pageAction.setPopup({
            tabId: sender.tab.id, 
            popup: "path/to/popup.html"
        });
    }
});

/* When the tab's address changes/reloads, 
 * clear the popup and reset the icon.
 * (If applicable, the newly injected content script will send a new message.) */
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.status === "loading") {
        chrome.pageAction.setIcon({
            tabId: tabId,
            path: "path/to/inactive/icon.png."
        });
        chrome.pageAction.setPopup({
            tabId: tabId, 
            popup: ""
        });
    }
});
```

---

Also, note:

- The `activeTab` permission is a subset of the `tabs` permission, so it makes no sense to use them together.
- It might be less confusing to your users if you hid the page-action icon when not on `Facebook` (using **[`chrome.pageAction.hide(...)`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#method-hide)** and **[`chrome.pageAction.show(...)`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#method-show)**).

Comment: I used the show hide method. and I had to use send.tab.id not tabId as it was not defined. other than that it worked perfectly thanks